# Incrementing names of form elements javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a bunch of form elements that can be continuously added with an "Add Field" button.
Now I want to give these fields incremental names like

input-name-xyz-1, input-name-xyz-2, ....

input-name-abc-1, input-name-abc-2, .....

foo-1, foo-2, foo-3, ....

and so on.

The "Add Field" button calls a function called addField() which manipulates the dom elements to replicate the nodes.

I am having problem with creating the logic for incremental names. Can you guys help me??

Here's the code that I'm working on (The form elements are laravel generated)

```
/*THE HTML*/
<section class="input">
        {{ Form::label('achievements', 'Achievements:') }}
        <input class="count" name="achievements-count" type="hidden" value="1">
        <p class="addedField input">
            {{ Form::input('input-name-xyz-1', $competition_games, Input::old('achievement-competition'), array('id' => 'achievement-competition')); }}
            {{ Form::select('input-name-abc-1', array('Year - Place'), Input::old('achievement-year'), array('id' => 'achievement-year')) }}
            {{ Form::select('foo-1',    array('Position', 'Gold' => 'Gold', 'Silver' => 'Silver', 'Bronze' => 'Bronze', 'Participant' => 'Participant'), Input::old('achievement-achieved'), array('id' => 'achievement-achieved')) }}
        </p>
        <a onclick="addField(this)">+</a>
    </section>
```

and the javascript

```
function addField(elem){
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    var addName = parent.id;
    var count = ++(parent.getElementsByClassName("count")[0].value);
    var lastNode = parent.getElementsByClassName("addedField")[count-2];
    var clone = lastNode.cloneNode(true); 
    var nodes = clone.childNodes;
    for(i=0; i<nodes.length-1; i++){
        nodes[i].value = "";
        nodes[i].name = //I need the logic right here//.
    }
    if(count == 2)
        clone.innerHTML += "<a class='removeLink' onClick='removeField(this)'>X</a>";
    parent.insertBefore(clone,elem);
}
```

-- Regards, Aayush Shrestha

Comment: Some code to show what you're currently doing would help ;-)

Comment: Yes, we can help you. But to solve the problems we would need to see them…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to increment any numbers at end of a string.

```
function incNumAtEnd(s) {
  return s.replace(/\d$/, function(match, ofs, str) {
    return (parseInt(match) + 1).toString();
  });
}
```

And here's the usage in your code.

```
nodes[i].name = incNumAtEnd(nodes[i].name);
```